# Show that $f(t)\leqslant f(a)e^{K(t-a)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that for $f \in \mathcal C^1([a,a+\varepsilon])$ positive and satisfies the differential inequality $f' \leqslant Kf\log f$, we have $$f(t)\leqslant f(a)e^{K(t-a)} \text{ for } t\in [a,a+\varepsilon].$$

**My attempt :**
since $f$ is positive we can divide by $f$ and then integrate
$$ \dfrac{f'}{f} \leqslant K \log(f) \implies \int_a^t(\log(f(s)))'ds \leqslant \int_a^t K\log(f(s))ds  ,$$ then
$$ \log(f(t))-\log(f(a)) \leqslant\int_a^t K\log(f(s))ds , $$
thus $$f(t) \leqslant f(a) \int_a^t K\log(f(s))ds  $$

I got stuck here.

N.B : I have tried to use Gronwall inequality but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

That's not true. Counterexample: $f(t) = e^2 e^{2K(t-a)}$ satisfies

$$f'(t) = 2K e^2 e^{2K(t-a)} = 2K f(t) \le K f \log f.$$
Since $\log f \ge 2$. But
$$ f(t) = e^2 e^{2K(t-a)} = f(a)e^{K(t-a)}e^{K(t-a)} > f(a) e^{K(t-a)}$$
for all $t >a$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! so, my teacher made a mistake ?!

Comment: @H_K Yes I guess so.